# std::set find behavior with char * type

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, stdset

I have below code line:

```
const char *values[] = { "I", "We", "You", "We"};
std::set<const char*> setValues;

for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {

    const char *val = values[i];
    std::set<const char*>::iterator it = setValues.find( val );

    if( it == setValues.end() ) {
        setValues.insert( val );
    }
    else {
        cout << "Existing value" << endl;
    }
}
```

With this I am trying to insert non-repeated values in a `set`, but somehow code is not hitting to print for existing element and duplicate value is getting inserted.

What is wrong here?

Comment: You are storing consecutive pointers so of course they are different.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a string and a pointer?

Comment: Why are you using C-strings from the 1970s?

Answer (score 5):

You should define less predicate for const char* and pass into the set template to make the set object works correctly with pointers:

```
  struct cstrless {
    bool operator()(const char* a, const char* b) const {
      return strcmp(a, b) < 0;
    }
  };
  std::set<const char*, cstrless> setValues;
```

Comment: No, you should use `std::string`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it depends on task. For example you can have string array as linear big string like the following: "one\0two\0three\0...." and pointers to  word begin. In that case you could use such approach to find the item.

Answer (score 4):

The `std::set<T>::find` uses a default operator `<` of the type `T`.
Your type is `const char*`. This is a pointer to an address in memory so the `find` method just compares address in memory of given string to addresses in memory of all strings from `set`. These addresses are different for each string (unless compiler optimizes it out).

You need to tell `std::set` how to compare strings correctly. I can see that AnatolyS already wrote how to do it in his answer.

Comment: @user2079303 Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use a custom comparison function object, `std::set` uses `operator<(const key_type&,key_type&)` by default. Two pointers are equal if, and only if they point to the same object.

Here is an example of three objects:

```
char a[] = "apple";
char b[] = "apple";
const char (&c)[6] = "apple"
```

First two are arrays, the third is an lvalue reference that is bound to a string literal object that is also an array. Being separate objects, their address is of course also different. So, if you were to write:

```
setValues.insert(a)
bool is_in_map = setValues.find("apple") != setValues.end();
```

The value of `is_in_map` would be `false`, because the set contains only the address of the string in `a`, and not the address of the string in the literal - even though the content of the strings are same.

Solution: Don't use `operator<` to compare pointers to c strings. Use `std::strcmp` instead. With `std::set`, this means using a custom comparison object. However, you aren't done with caveats yet. You must still make sure that the strings stay in memory as long as they are pointed to by the keys in the set. For example, this would be a mistake:

```
char a[] = "apple";
setValues.insert(a);
return setValues; // oops, we returned setValues outside of the scope
                  // but it contains a pointer to the string that
                  // is no longer valid outside of this scope
```

Solution: Take care of scope, or just use `std::string`.

<sub>(This answer plagiarises my own answer about `std::map` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38447150/2079303))</sub>